# Weird session issue with Rails 3 reset_session and cookies.delete(...) in the same controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, cookies, activesupport

In my logout action I'm doing this:

```
reset_session
cookies.delete(:rememberme)
redirect_to root_url
```

But the session is not being destroyed.

When I inspect the headers, the request sent to my logout action clearly includes the session ID:

```
Cookie: hiddenalerts=site_vrfy_124258; __utmz=REMOVED_INFO.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); elpriv=REMOVED_INFO; SESSID=b39a9a89bb6a39ea91b620fe0da392ed; __utma=REMOVED_INFO; __utmc=REMOVED_INFO; __utmb=REMOVED_INFO
```

But the response only clears the rememberme cookie, it doesn't clear the session cookie:

```
Set-Cookie: rememberme=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
```

If I compare this with the same headers when I comment out the rememberme cookie deletion.  The request looks the same:

```
Cookie: hiddenalerts=site_vrfy_124258; __utmz=REMOVED_INFO.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); elpriv=REMOVED_INFO; SESSID=b39a9a89bb6a39ea91b620fe0da392ed; __utma=REMOVED_INFO; __utmc=REMOVED_INFO; __utmb=REMOVED_INFO
```

But the response looks more like I'd expect (and my session is correctly destroyed):

```
Set-Cookie: SESSID=50640523cf32b5b0fe8c93eb16aba6dc; path=/; HttpOnly
```

Has anyone else experienced this?  I can only assume that the session handler and the ApplicationController don't hold the same reference to the cookies, so if you modify the cookies in the controller this clobbers anything that reset_session has done.  I can work around this problem by manually deleting the session cookie, but I'd like to understand what's happening and if there's a known workaround first.

Obviously I need the ability to clear a "remember me" cookie during the logout process, otherwise the user will simply be immediately logged back in.

EDIT | Issue raised as a bug.  I'll work around it for now. https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/6763-deleting-a-cookie-and-calling-reset_session-in-the-same-controller-action-does-not-send-new-session-cookie

Comment: I'm running into similar issues. Rails cookie handling seems to be buggy for a while now. Can you post how you worked around it?

Comment: I actually tracked the problem down to my caching proxy and not Rails itself.  The proxy was clobbering the `Set-Cookie:` headers together.  But if you're wondering what my work around was before I found that issue, I just changed my controller action to `if cookies[:rememberme]; cookies.delete(:rememberme); redirect_to(request.url); end`, so it effectively just cleared the cookie and reset the session over two requests.

Comment: I also found that in functional tests, secure cookies go unseen unless you call `@request.env["HTTPS"] = "on"`... which seems silly, but anyway.

Comment: @d11wtq, +1 for your solution being of significant value to solving a different problem that i had.

Answer (score 0):

Just to ensure, but are you assigning this cookie to the right key? cookies[:rememberme]? The cookie will not be deleted if it's not finding your hash attr.

Comment: It is correctly deleting the rememberme cookie.  The problem is that is doesn't send the new session ID in the Set-Cookie: header unless I don't delete the cookie.  I've worked around it, but it seems like a stale cookie data bug in Rails to me.